# How to reorder an API call to a custom order by API ID?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api

A bit of a niche question but it has challenged me, see if you can solve it.

I have this array of sports leagues ranked from best to worst by their respective API IDs.

```
const arrOrderedLeague = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
    34, 39, 45, 48, 140, 142, 135, 137, 78, 81, 61, 65, 66, 88,
    94, 96, 253, 203, 262, 179, 185, 144, 188, 169, 40, 41, 42,
    43, 235, 207, 218, 141, 136,333, 307, 197, 62, 79, 80, 128, 
    130, 292, 98, 101, 103, 106, 113, 119, 283, 71, 73, 265, 239, 211, 89 ]
```

All though the number 89 is lower than 211, 211 is the better league.

The issue is when I call the API it follows a random order. I am considerably weak when it comes to arrays so how would I make it follow the order I want?

Extra Info:

This is a console.log of the API Call, as you can see, league 73 is logged before 262, but since league 262 comes earlier in my array than 73, I want it to be logged ahead, this likely requires making a new array with some function unknown to me but I'm not sure what it is.

```
2: Object { fixture: {…}, league: {…}, teams: {…}, … }
​​
fixture: Object { id: 854430, referee: "Savio Pereira Sampaio, Brazil", timezone: "UTC", … }
​​
goals: Object { home: 3, away: 0 }
​​
league: Object { **id: 73**, name: "Copa Do Brasil", country: "Brazil", … }
​​
score: Object { halftime: {…}, fulltime: {…}, extratime: {…}, … }
​​
teams: Object { home: {…}, away: {…} }
​​
<prototype>: Object { … } 

3: Object { fixture: {…}, league: {…}, teams: {…}, … }
​​
fixture: Object { id: 861506, referee: "Jorge Antonio Perez Duran, Mexico", timezone: "UTC", … }
​​
goals: Object { home: 1, away: 2 }
​​
league: Object { **id: 262**, name: "Liga MX", country: "Mexico", … }
​​
score: Object { halftime: {…}, fulltime: {…}, extratime: {…}, … }
​​
teams: Object { home: {…}, away: {…} }
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
```

Less Needed but here is the API Call itself:

```
const settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/fixtures?date=2022-05-13",
    "method": "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    "headers": {
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "v3.football.api-sports.io",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "API-KEY"
    }
};
$.ajax(settings).done(function (data) {

    const newArr = data.response.filter(el => arrWant.includes(el.league.id));
    console.log(newArr)
    });
```

If you need any clarification please leave a comment, thanks for anyone who even tries!

[Json Of Response (I think idk though)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fZ5G.png)

Comment: @barmar can you please help mate.

Base of what I have researched, the answer is something like:

newArr.sort(function(a, b){  
 return newArr.indexOf(a) - arrWant.indexOf(b);
  });

But this still doesnt order it properly, see if you can solve it, I understand if you cant.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the response

Comment: @mstephen19 there should be a sample of the response in my question. You can see elements 2 and 3 ([2,3]). 

If you want some other response please clarify I will provide it, thanks for trying.

Comment: That is not a JSON sample of the response, that is something you directly copied from console and pasted here. What does the response data look like? I really don't wanna go get an API key for this API lol

Comment: @mstephen19 ok, check the end of my question, would that be the Json (I'm new if you couldn't tell) if not how would I get it lol

Comment: @mstephen19 I will put the fortuna Czech league higher up in the ranking if you solve this I promise

Comment: You've got yourself a deal

Comment: footballify.net/test is the website feel free to take all the info you need from there

and dont worry the API-KEY is IP and Domain protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got your solution, but there's an issue: The API endpoint you're reaching isn't returning all the leagues you want. It is returning 302 items, but only 16 of them match some of the 69 league IDs you've specified.

Nonetheless, in order to achieve the order you want, you can:

1. Fetch the data
2. Map over your desired IDs, returning the corresponding item from the API response. If it doesn't exist, this field will be undefined
3. Filter out all the undefined values

```js
const desiredOrder = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 39, 45, 48, 140, 142, 135, 137, 78, 81, 61, 65, 66, 88, 94, 96, 253, 203, 262, 179, 185,
    144, 188, 169, 40, 41, 42, 43, 235, 207, 218, 141, 136, 333, 307, 197, 62, 79, 80, 128, 130, 292, 98, 101, 103, 106, 113, 119, 283, 71, 73,
    265, 239, 211, 89,
];

const run = async () => {
    // Make the request
    const res = await fetch('https://v3.football.api-sports.io/fixtures?date=2022-05-13', {
        headers: {
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
            // Take my API key idc
            'X-RapidAPI-Key': '9e4b7483aa00fa65f63f96c52c184754',
        },
    });

    // Convert response body to JSON and grab the "response" property (array)
    const json = (await res.json())?.response;

    // Loop through the desired IDs and for each return the corresponding API response item
    const ordered = desiredOrder.map((id) => json.find(({ league }) => league?.id === id));

    // Remove duplicate (undefined) values to shorten array, then filter out all undefineds
    const filtered = [...new Set(ordered)].filter(item => item !== undefined)

    console.log(filtered);
};

run();
```

Though this array is not the same length as the `desiredOrder` array (due to the API not returning all the desired data), it maintains the order desired.

Comment: no that part is perfect, it was never meant to show all of the desired ids, only the ones that are occurring today.

and initially I got this error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. script.js:51:13
    run https://footballify.net/test/script.js:51
    AsyncFunctionThrow self-hosted:642
    (Async: async)
    <anonymous> https://footballify.net/test/script.js:54

Then it fixed itself and works amazingly, I will complete my end of the bargain now of course, thanks so much! @mstephen19

Comment: I have an issue with the code, when there are multiple games from the same league such as 2 czech league games on same day, only one of them will load and the other is removed from the data. Is there any fix to this?

Comment: any clue???????

Comment: I'd recommend doing it yourself

Comment: I was able to do it :)